Как сериализовать и десериализовать ObservableCollection<DataGrid> с контекстом данных DataTable в json файл
Подскажите пожалуйста.
У меня есть ObservableCollection<DataGrid> DataGrids {get; set;}, который отображаю в визуальном элементе xaml ItemsControl.
С помощью команды я добавляю в эту коллекцию DataGrid с контекстом данных DataTable.
Command = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
{
    DataGrid datagrid = new();
    DataTable datatable = new();

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) datatable.Columns.Add(Subject[j]);

    datagrid.ItemsSource = datatable.DefaultView;
    DataGrids.Add(datagrid);
});

Названия для колонок
public List<string> Subject = new List<string>() { "Математика", "Физика", "Химия", "Биология", "Геометрия" };

Как можно сериализовать ObservableCollcetion<DataGrid> DataGrids {get; set;}, так чтобы сериализовывались данные строк и названия колонок в json файл, и можно было десериализовать обратно при входе в окно, чтобы также все оставалось в порядке названия колонок и данные строк.
Пробовал дергать свойство ItemsSource через Linq, но падают исключения, или сериализация неправильная, также десериализация кривая.
Подскажите как сделать, может другой подход нужен?
Миниатюра. Колонок может быть разное количество, данные - просто строки. Сериализую в json файл в директорию.

xaml код.
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataGrids}"/>


Контрол нельзя сериализовать. А так, доставайте из него ItemsSource и сериализуйте. Но запихивая контролы в ObservableCollection вы явно что-то делаете не так. Не вижу в этой манипуляции никакого смысла. но падают исключения - код покажите, который не работает, отредактируйте вопрос. Чтобы подсказать правильное решение, нужно понимать, какая задача вообще решается. И что там у вас в XAML и как оно должно выглядеть. Коллекция есть, а как используется - загадка, разметку ItemsControl покажите.

Мне нужно отображать неизвестное количество таблиц, которые можно настроить т.е. DataGrid с контекстом данных DataTable, но не знаю как правильно сделать в xaml поэтому засунул в коллекцию и отображаю в itemsControl, получается не правильно, как можно тогда сделать отображение таблиц количество которых будет меняться?

Ну вот покажите как вы сделали, наверное проблема в том что вы не умеете использовать ItemTemplate. Что вводите в ячейки - тоже надо знать. Если сериализуем, то что именно? Типы колонок в DataTable вы не задали. И самое главное - сериализовать во что? В куда?

Кстати, вот этот Subject - список предметов захардкожен будет или будет изменяться пользователем? Если захардкожен, то всё делается проще простого.

Добавил, картинку, да Subject будет изменяться, это я сделал пока просто для проверки

XAML разметку ItemsControl покажите, в третий раз прошу. В ячейки что будет вводиться, числа или просто текст, или что?

Добавил, xaml код, в ячейках будет просто текст

"Мух от котлет" отсоединит. Вы сейчас берете UI компонент (DataGrid) и работаете с ним, он у вас отвечает и за данные, и за отображение, а еще вы хотите его сделать ответственным и за хранение... Сделайте класс, который будет в себе содержать нужные свойства, далее сделайте коллекцию этого класса и заполните ее. Вот у вас уже данные в отдельном месте и вы можете смело эту коллекцию де/сериализовать. После привяжите это все в XAML и отобразите нужные столбцы, готово. Запомните только то, что вы не должны хотеть в C# коде работать с XAML объектами.

Начнём с самого главного - контролов не должно быть в данных.
ObservableCollection<DataTable> Tables { get; } = new();

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

Здесь же в XAML и разные настройки для DataGrid можно будет прописать.
Теперь создание таблицы.
Command = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
{
    DataTable datatable = new();

    foreach (string subject in Subject)
    {
        datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(subject, typeof(string),
        {
            AllowDBNull = false,
            DefaultValue = ""
        }));
    }

    Tables.Add(datatable);
});

Теперь сериализация в файл
public void SerializeDataTable(string path, DataTable table)
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> data = new();
    DataRow[] rows = table.Select();
    foreach (string name in table.Columns.Select(x => x.ColumnName))
    {
        data[name] = rows.Select(row => (string)row[name])).ToArray();
    }
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    File.WriteAllText(path, json);
}

И в обратную сторону
public DataTable DeserializeDataTable(string path)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
    Dictionary<string, string[]> data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);
    DataTable table = new();

    foreach (string subject in data.Keys)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(subject, typeof(string),
        {
            AllowDBNull = false,
            DefaultValue = ""
        }));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data[data.Keys[0]].Length; i++)
    {
        string[] rowData = data.Values.Select(x => x[i]).ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(rowData);
    }
    return table;
}

Можно считать что это решение "в лоб", и по-взрослому это делается через JSON конвертеры. Но так тоже сработает, у вас же не будет миллионов строк или колонок в этих таблицах, поэтому не должно тормозить.

Спасибо большое, выручили
